# Disable payment gateway when specific products in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, cart

I want to unset the payment method 'bacs' for the product ID 6197.

I have tried the code below, but this does not have the desired result.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'wp_unset_gateway_by_id', 10, 2 );` 
function wp_unset_gateway_by_id( $available_gateways, $products) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $unset = false;
    $product_ids = array('6197');

    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids ) || ( $product->is_type('variation') && in_array( $product->get_parent_id(), $product_ids ) ) ){
        unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] ); 
        return $available_gateways;
    }
}
```

---

I believe I am doing something wrong, but I am relatively new to this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$products` is not passed as argument to the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` filter hook

Apply it in the following way:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $payment_gateways ) {
    // Not on admin
    if ( is_admin() ) return $payment_gateways;
    
    // The targeted product ids (several can be added, separated by a comma)
    $targeted_ids = array( 6197 );

    // Flag
    $found = false;

    // WC Cart
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( array_intersect( $targeted_ids, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $found ) {       
        // Bacs
        if ( isset( $payment_gateways['bacs'] ) ) {
            unset( $payment_gateways['bacs'] );
        }       
    }
    
    return $payment_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 10, 1 );
```